# Android SettingsActivity crashes on Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android

I'm new to Android, and I have this error when I'm trying to launch the `SettingsActivity`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.udacity.frliran.sunshine, PID: 24887
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1850)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:410)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:177)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:170)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
at android.preference.PreferenceActivity$HeaderAdapter.getView(PreferenceActivity.java:349)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2820)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1174)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1062)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:614)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:874)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2888)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Me
```

Here is the `SettingsActivity` code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            }  else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || WeatherPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class WeatherPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_weather);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key)));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a `pref_header.xml` file that came when I added the `SettingsActivity`:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:fragment="com.udacity.frliran.sunshine.SettingsActivity$WeatherPreferenceFragment"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_weather" />
</preference-headers>
```

And this is the `pref_weather.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_weather_title_location"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <!-- NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
         dismiss it. -->
    <!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
    <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_units_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_weather_title_units"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_weather_default_units"
        android:entries="@array/pref_weather_units_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_weather_units_values"
        android:negativeButtonText="@null"
        android:positiveButtonText="@null" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I added the `SettingsActivity` it had a default of settings that I did not need. I thought it had something to do with this so I removed them, but it didn't solve it.

The error doesn't point me where to search for this error to fix it, and I don't know how to start investigate for a solution...

Comment: Can you post you code..?

Comment: I don't know what code to post... This error doesn't point me anywhere..

Comment: @LiranFriedman you should post code of your SettingsActivity + its xml layout file

Comment: I've added it to the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this answer is the best option, but since I have no other answer and it was my last resort to solving this error so I posted it.

This is what I did:

I copied out the settings activity and then deleted it and added a new `SettingsActivity` to the project, then I merged the code I copied from my first `SettingsActivity` to the new one and it just works.
I think that maybe there are some resources or relations that the IDE adds when adding a `SettingsActivity` that may have been missing earlier, so there was actually no problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize ImageView?
Because  this error is due to ttwo reasons.
1. ImageView not initialized
2. R.drawable.image_source does not exist.

Go to line no. 74 and post that code here.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to look for ?

Comment: Line 74 of what file ?

Comment: Can you just copy here your settingactivity

Comment: I've added it to the question above

Comment: I am not able to debug it properly as the files are not complete, Just debug it using android debugger and mark break points and see where it is broken, you will find the error, from my point of you, this kind of error comes when some component of activity is not initialized or the activity not getting resource properly.

Comment: I've added several breakpoints for debugging, but none of them failed, it keeps on and on until I release the debugger and it crashes... there is also this code in the `pref_headers.xml` file that came with the `SettingsActivity` by default: `<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:fragment="com.udacity.frliran.sunshine.SettingsActivity$WeatherPreferenceFragment"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_weather" />
</preference-headers>`

Comment: I've also added it to the question above

Comment: can you mail me your project or upload it on github?

Comment: Where do I find you email ?

Comment: ashish231992@gmail.com

Comment: It says that I can't send it for security reasons... What files do I need to delete ?

Comment: upload it on github and give me th link, i will copy it from there

Comment: Seems that there was no problem with the code. I've posted an answer, that I've just deleted the activity and re-added a new one and pasted the code from the first one to the new one. I think there are some resources or something that the IDE adds automatically...